# GeoProof error, art_render_invoke: no image source given?

Tags: geometry, proof

This is basically all it is, on Windows 8, running GeoProof, I get the message: "art_render_invoke: no image source given." I do not know how to fix it, no matter what I have tried, it pops up this error.

To recreate:

1. Install GeoProof
2. Run GeoProof